# GEE error: Unable to compute error margin in invalid area of projection (EPSG:32750: ........0))

Tags: google-earth-engine, random-forest

i tried to visualize the regression from random forest, but it cannon appear in console or map, the variable predictor has been export by same scale and crs. why this is happen?

```
// Display the input imagery and the regression classification.
   //get dictionaries of min & max predicted value
  var regressionMin = (regression.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.min(),
    scale: 30, 
    crs: crs,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 5
  }));
  var regressionMax = (regression.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.max(),
    scale: 30, 
    crs: crs,
    bestEffort: true,
    tileScale: 5
  }));


// Add to map
var viz = {palette: palette, min: regressionMin.getNumber('predicted').getInfo(), max: regressionMax.getNumber('predicted').getInfo()};
Map.addLayer(regression, viz, 'Regression');
```

[here is the script of my project](https://code.earthengine.google.com/93f5647901f1b32e616ca7706e9eb4fa)
it happens in line 177

Comment: Adding the code is not enough for explaining your problem. Add some context of your code and the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

`reduceRegion` produces a single number; you shouldn't be trying to display in on a map.  Just print it.

For anyone else to be able to help you, you will need to shre your assets, simplify your script and post a complete example (not a link).